# FileNotFoundException at URL

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the request from the php url.File not found exception occurred at runtime.I mentioned the error line in the below code.Stacktrace seems to be doesn't get the response from the url.

**StackTrace:**

```
10-30 05:57:23.000: D/URL(2735): Connectionhttp://example.php

10-30 05:13:37.600: W/System.err(2577): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://myapi.phpBa
10-30 05:13:37.600: W/System.err(2577):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
10-30 05:13:37.600: W/System.err(2577):     at com.manishkpr.autotextviewexample.JsonParse.getParseJsonWCF(JsonParse.java:32)
10-30 05:13:37.610: W/System.err(2577):     at com.manishkpr.autotextviewexample.SuggestionAdapter$1.performFiltering(SuggestionAdapter.java:39)
10-30 05:13:37.610: W/System.err(2577):     at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
10-30 05:13:37.610: W/System.err(2577):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-30 05:13:37.610: W/System.err(2577):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-30 05:13:37.610: W/System.err(2577):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

**JSONParse.java:**

```
public List<SuggestGetSet> getParseJsonWCF(String sName)
        {
         List<SuggestGetSet> ListData = new ArrayList<SuggestGetSet>();
         try {
            String temp=sName.replace(" ","%20");
            URL js = new URL("example.php"+temp);

            Log.d("URL","Connection"+js);

            URLConnection urlConnection  = js.openConnection();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));  ---32 nd line
            String line = reader.readLine();
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(line);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("search");
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject r = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                ListData.add(new SuggestGetSet(r.getString("id"), 
r.getString("name")));
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
         return ListData;

        }
```

Comment: is the url you are accessing is a valid one ??

Comment: URL was working.thats not my url.I didn't show it.Thats an example @Panther

Comment: what is in temp variable

Comment: @raj  If I search first two letter,it shows an autocomplete list view via url

Comment: **//192.123.1.10/public/v1/tab/example.phpBa **  is that what you want to access  !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replace this lines

```
String temp=sName.replace(" ","%20");
URL js = new URL("http://192.11.my api.php"+temp);
```

with

```
String temp=URLEncoder.encode("http://192.11.my api.php/"+sName, "UTF-8");
URL js = new URL(temp);
```

Comment: If I do like this,I am getting Malformed url exception

Comment: do check your ip address its not correct generally it looks like 192.168.1.122 but yours is just 192.11 , can you debug it and post the url what your getting in temp variable

Comment: URL was working.thats not my url.I didn't show it.Thats an example.I am edited and post the log.d

Comment: after php you should have / that is what i expect you to do

Comment: You are great.working fine after added the /.Thank you