# Sometimes FileNotFoundException at Url

Tags: inputstream, httpurlconnection, java-io

Sorry for bad English.

My problem is so similar this issue "[FileNotFoundException at URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649540/filenotfoundexception-at-url)"
but sometimes it gives error and doesnt continue but sometimes it works perfectly. This problem is in first connection.What can be the problem that causes it works sometimes and doesnt work sometimes?

```
10-10 02:19:41.128    9667-9819/? W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://cdn59.my.mail.ru/v/59908302.mp4?slave[]=s%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fvideo-cephgw1.i%3A8080%2Frados%2F59908302-v&p=f&expire_at=1476068400&touch=1475880462&reg=76&sign=dd01f023e682705a105440ab5e93f5cb38cfeadd
10-10 02:19:41.128    9667-9819/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
10-10 02:19:41.128    9667-9819/? W/System.err﹕ at makgun.kturk.MRDownloader$1.doInBackground(MRDownloader.java:105)
10-10 02:19:41.128    9667-9819/? W/System.err﹕ at makgun.kturk.MRDownloader$1.doInBackground(MRDownloader.java:39)
10-10 02:19:41.128    9667-9819/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-10 02:19:41.128    9667-9819/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-10 02:19:41.128    9667-9819/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-10 02:19:41.128    9667-9819/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-10 02:19:41.128    9667-9819/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-10 02:19:41.128    9667-9819/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

MRDownloader:

```
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try {
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" +name;
                File file = new File(path);
                int total;
                if (file.exists())total=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length()));
                else total=0;
                //New Added
                if (urls[0].startsWith("//"))urls[0]="http:"+urls[0];
                //New Added finished
                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + file.length() + "-");
                if(!Cookie.isEmpty())
                urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", "video_key=" +Cookie);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(7000);
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(7000);
                urlConnection.connect();

                int lenghtOfFile = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                PD.setMax(lenghtOfFile+total);
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                //    int total=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length()));
                int count;
                Log.d("MakgunLENGHT-OF-FILE", Integer.toString(lenghtOfFile));

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    PD.setProgress(total);
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                    if (pause){output.flush();output.close();input.close();if (PD.isShowing()) PD.dismiss();break;}
                }
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

You can use this link to try it. [TryLink](https://my.mail.ru/+/video/meta/5335264755126894891).
When you request this link it generates "video_key" cookie and response body includes all of information what you need like stream URL of video. I dont copy all of java file so if you need I can add more. Thanks.

Comment: Nowadays, I have had time to understand this and finally I find out its why and when happens. I want to share this for other users. Its why is that it happens whenever server send bad request and for this site sometimes send Service Unavaible 503 and this code failures. But adding a condition to repeat max 10 times it works like a charm. At least one click is enough and it repeats max 10 times and generally it get 2xx response code from server after 2-3 try times. If 2xx code received it breaks the loop. And it doesnt reapet any more. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, I have had time to understand this and finally I find out its why and when happens. I want to share this for other users. **Its why is that** it happens whenever server send bad request and for this site sometimes send **"Service Unavaible 503"** and this code failures. But ***adding a condition*** to repeat max 10 times it works like a charm. At least one click is enough and it repeats max 10 times and generally **it gets 2xx response code from server after 2-3 times tried**. If 2xx code received it breaks the loop. And it doesnt reapet any more. This solved my problem.

```
    int x = 1;
while (true) {
    //otherStuffs...
    if (responseCode == 503) {
    Log.d("makgunResponseCode503", "Now ResponseCode is 503 repeating " + x + " times");
    x++;
    }
    else
    {Log.d("makgunResponseCode", "ResponseCode is: " + responseCode);break}
    if (x > 10) break;
}
```

Comment: Also you can look for [HTTP_STATUS_CODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error)